# How to aggregate metrics across URIs in webclient?

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

I have a `WebClient` that makes calls to the backend:

`https://example.com/foo?q=1`
`https://example.com/foo?q=2`
`https://example.com/foo?q=3`

I want to collect metrics across endpoints. Currently, every `uri` is collected separately.

Is there is a way to configure `MetricsWebClientFilterFunction` to achieve that?

Comment: What backend are you using? Are you saying you want all 3 of those calls to be considered a single metrics? like `https://example.com/foo?q={queryId}` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to have them treated as one.

Comment: Can yo please add a code snippet for how you are calling the webclient url? Or you using templates there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@checketts suggested using uri templates and this is ihmo way simpler solution.

So in WebClient instead of using:

```kotlin
.uri { uri -> uri.path("foo").queryParam("q", "1").build() }
```

I used:

```kotlin
 .uri("foo?q={id}", "1")
```

Underneath the latter `WebClient` sets attribute:

```java
attribute(URI_TEMPLATE_ATTRIBUTE, uriTemplate);
```

which is later used in `WebClientExchangeTags`:

```java
String uri = (String) request.attribute(URI_TEMPLATE_ATTRIBUTE).orElseGet(() -> request.url().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I added custom `WebClientExchangeTagsProvider` and registered it as a bean:

```kotlin
class SameUriWebClientExchangeTagsProvider : WebClientExchangeTagsProvider {
    override fun tags(request: ClientRequest, response: ClientResponse?, throwable: Throwable?): Iterable<Tag> {
        val method = WebClientExchangeTags.method(request)
        val uri = tag(request)
        val clientName = WebClientExchangeTags.clientName(request)
        val status = WebClientExchangeTags.status(response, throwable)
        val outcome = WebClientExchangeTags.outcome(response)
        return listOf(method, uri, clientName, status, outcome)
    }

    private fun tag(request: ClientRequest): Tag {
        val uri = request.attribute(WebClient::class.java.name + ".uriTemplate")
            .orElseGet {
                request.url().toString()
            } as String

        return Tag.of("uri", URI(uri).path)
    }
}
```